# Prevent download of unused SVG <image xlink> depending on screensize/media queries

Tags: svg, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following SVG code directly embedded in the middle of an HTML page:

```
<!-- Desktop SVG -->
<svg class="desktop">
  <g>
    <image xlink:href="/images/desktop.png" />
    <a xlink:href="/link1">
      <g>
        <circle r="10" cy="84" cx="123" />
      </g>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>

<!-- Mobile SVG -->
<svg class="mobile">
  <g>
    <image xlink:href="/images/mobile.png" />
    <a xlink:href="/link1">
      <g>
        <circle r="10" cy="5" cx="10" />
      </g>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Based on the screen size, CSS hides one or the other, and this all works nicely.

The problem is that both the PNG images are downloaded on mobile and on desktop, even though only one will actually be displayed, which is poor for performance.

Is it possible to prevent this double download of `<image>` tag `xlinks` based on media queries (like you can do with CSS backgrounds)?

The SVG contains clickable links (via `<a xlink:href="...">` tags) and they don't seem to work when the SVG is loaded from an external file, so loading the whole SVG code via an external file and using this as a background-image is not an option.

Comment: you can save those two svg's as seperate files and attach them as background image via css

Comment: Unfortunately not in this case as the SVG contains clickable links (via `<a xlink:href="...">` tags) and they don't seem to work when the SVG is loaded from an external file. Will add that to the question to make it clear.

Comment: clickable links won't work when SVG is loaded as an <image> either, unless the link is in the main document and links the entire image.

Comment: The `<image>` tags are PNGs. The whole structure is an SVG which contains those `<image>` tags and various `<a>` tags. I've updated the code in the question so hopefully that makes sense. As I say this works, except for the double downloads issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not currently possible.

Lucky as the PNGs cover the whole space of the SVG, it's possible to pull them out of the SVG leaving just the xlinks, which achieves what I want:

```
<style>
.svg-desktop-image {
        background-image: url("/images/desktop.png");
        background-size: contain;
}
.svg-mobile-image {
        background-image: url("/images/mobile.png");
        background-size: contain;
}
</style>
<!-- Desktop SVG -->
<div class="desktop">
  <svg class="svg-desktop-image">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="/link1">
        <g>
          <circle r="10" cy="84" cx="123" />
        </g>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- Mobile SVG -->
<div class="mobile">
  <svg class="svg-mobile-image">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="/link1">
        <g>
          <circle r="10" cy="5" cx="10" />
        </g>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Will leave this question open for a bit longer in case anyone has any other suggestions and then accept my own answer if not.

Comment: This would have been my recommendation as well.